# How can I get a value from firebase and and put it in a text in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a simple problem which is how to get specific values from database Firebase.

For example, I want to get the value of "name" and put it in text. How can I do that? Can you write a detailed code?
[image: My cloudfirestore]

```
  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String myuid;
  FirebaseUser currentUser;


  // To get id
  void _loadCurrentUser() {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
  setState(() { // call setState to rebuild the view
    this.currentUser = user;
  });
  });
   }


@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_loadCurrentUser();
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
myuid = currentUser.uid;

var getname;
Future<void> getName() async {
  DocumentSnapshot ds =
  await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(myuid).get();
  getname = ds.data['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String name;

Future<null> getName() async {
  DocumentSnapshot document = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(FirebaseUser().uid).get();
name = document.data['name']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get data from the Firestore Database Document once

```
val docRef = db.collection("users").document("mhPtwy..........")
docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
        }
```

Comment: if you are using .add() it will create random string as a document id like mhptwyob... so you need to use known data like usersId for that. check the answer.

Comment: it s kotlin code to demonstrate the process of getting data from firestore. so put it for example when you click on a view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of cheeky way to get the data and store it in a variable

```
var name;
Future<void> getName(){
  DocumentSnapshot ds = await 
       Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).get();
  name = ds.data['name']
}
```

then just throw that in your text field

```
Text(name);
```

Comment: Is it allowed to write `ds.data['name']`? The error; `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.` occurs